# Error in shinyApp(ui, server) : `server` missing from shinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I have this below code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI( dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "example"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(h3("text format"),
    mainPanel(
    infoBox("123", "Today's work", "Lots of pending", width = 6)
    infoBox("234", "Today's work", "completed", width = 6)
    ))))
server <- shinyServer({})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can someone help me out on the error?
Also I want  "Today's work" text in infoBox to be in normal case letters, not in bold case letters.

Comment: Have you tried adding a "," after your first infobox? Meaning `infoBox("123", "Today's work", "Lots of pending", width = 6), ...`.

Comment: Yes, fix the missing comma `,`, and use `server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session))`

Comment: yes, i tried the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){})
```

Here is the complete code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI( dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "example"),
                             dashboardSidebar(),
                             dashboardBody(h3("text format"),
                                           mainPanel(
                                             infoBox("123", "Today's work", "Lots of pending", width = 6),
                                             infoBox("234", "Today's work", "completed", width = 6)
                                           ))))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result: 
[image: ShinyApp]

Comment: Thank you. Can we convert text "Today's  work" from bold format to normal format?